# Javascript for CanvasJS CDN works in Notepad++ but not on Wordpress text editor

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I used the following code in Notepad++ and it worked fine for creating a pie chart of the different search engines when I opened it in chrome:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<script>
window.onload = function() {

var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer", {
    animationEnabled: true,
    title: {
        text: "Desktop Search Engine Market Share - 2016"
    },
    data: [{
        type: "pie",
        startAngle: 240,
        yValueFormatString: "##0.00\"%\"",
        indexLabel: "{label} {y}",
        dataPoints: [
            {y: 79.45, label: "Google"},
            {y: 7.31, label: "Bing"},
            {y: 7.06, label: "Baidu"},
            {y: 4.91, label: "Yahoo"},
            {y: 1.26, label: "Others"}
        ]
    }]
});
chart.render();

}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="chartContainer" style="height: 370px; width: 100%;"></div>
<script src="https://canvasjs.com/assets/script/canvasjs.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I attempted to put this into a plan text page on Wordpress and it returns a big white space with the dimensions of the `<div>` container.

I should mention that I am using an *Avada child theme*, and in the header.php file I have added the following:

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-y3tfxAZXuh4HwSYylfB+J125MxIs6mR5FOHamPBG064zB+AFeWH94NdvaCBm8qnd" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-vFJXuSJphROIrBnz7yo7oB41mKfc8JzQZiCq4NCceLEaO4IHwicKwpJf9c9IpFgh" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-alpBpkh1PFOepccYVYDB4do5UnbKysX5WZXm3XxPqe5iKTfUKjNkCk9SaVuEZflJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

I feel like the answer is something extremely simple thats happening with the Wordpress side, but I haven't developed a Wordpress theme yet so I'm a bit lost as to where to look.

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you check: 1. Console for any errors? 2. Rendered Html? 3. Network errors?

Comment: Yes sorry, I should have mentioned, I did check console for errors it didn't return anything

Comment: Use the proper functions in WordPress to enqueue scripts.  Most issues occur because developers don't utilise the wp_enqueue_script() function.

Comment: Okay and I put that in the functions.php file right?